# How to run a python script after an x amount of time it has just finished?

Tags: python, performance, time

I want to be able to run my python script which scans for something related to cryptocurrencies 1 minute after the same script has just been complete. Is this possible? Or could I maybe set a limit before the loop repeats itself or something?

The code I have isn't something I am willing to share due to its sensitive nature. It is a trading bot.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few solutions:

1. Use a cron job if you are on a unix like platform (you can use [this](https://crontab.guru/) for the syntax, or `man cron` in the terminal to learn more about it)
2. Create a long running python script that sleeps for one minute before executing your logic again. Something like this:

```
import time
while True:
    # execute code here
    time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it on Windows platform ,
You can create a batch file to run your script in cmd using the following command:

> start "" "path_to_python.exe" "path_to_python_script"

then create a task in windows task scheduler .

You can refer
https://dev.to/tharindadilshan/running-a-python-script-every-x-minutes-in-windows-10-3nm9 . It might helps.